# DateTimePicker to filter datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datetime, filter

I have an DataGridView with about 13000 records and I want to filter it by date. Problem is I don't know how! Currently if I want to filter the DGV according to string I use the following code

```
If TextBox1.TextLength > 0 Then
        frmReportMenu.ProjectBindingSource.Filter =_ 
String.Format("[User no] Like '*" & TextBox1.Text) & "*'"
    Else
        frmReportMenu.ProjectBindingSource.Filter = String.Empty
    End If
```

But I have no idea what to use for date, since date is not the same as String.Format

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter by two DateTimePicker dates, do this :

```
Dim DateFrom as string = String.Format("[YourDateField] >= '{0:yyyy-MM-dd}' ", DateTimePickerFrom.Value)
Dim DateTo as string = String.Format("[YourDateField] <= '{0:yyyy-MM-dd}' ", DateTimePickerTo.Value)

frmReportMenu.ProjectBindingSource.Filter = String.Format("{0} AND {1}", DateFrom, DateTo)
```